# Error en comparacion en Eclipse, dice que todo es distinto cuando no es así

Tags: eclipse, git, comparaciones

Buenos días,

Quería preguntar por qué mi Eclipse me dice que  dos archivos  son completamente distintos cuando no es así, he intentado cambiar el  método de comparación con directamente el `"text compare"` pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

Esta función es muy útil para comparar ramas en git y la verdad es que es una desgracia que no me funcione.

Aquí adjunto la foto de lo que ocurre. 
[image: Comparador textos]

Muchas gracias comunidad.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hmm...que no es distinto? No hay una línea mas en la ventana de la izquierda que en la derecha?

Comment: Por cierto, olvidé darte la bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Puedes pegar líneas de una y otra versión del fichero en la pregunta? Con las imágenes no podemos probar nada

Comment: Buenas, si, tiene cambios , ¿pero no beria de salir solo como diferencia esa linea?, perdonar pero en el proyecto en el que estoy no se me permite sacar codigo y lo mucho que he podido hacer es un pantallazo, perdonar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece ser que hay algún problema con los retornos de carro con Egit. [Aqui tienes una discusión sobre el tema](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/367532/895766/)

Se sugieren dos soluciones. Por un lado, decirle a Eclipse que ignore los espacios en blanco. [Aqui está explicado](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-68b.htm), se trata de ir a General > Compare/Patch y activar la opción `Ignore white spaces`.

La segunda solución se explica en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8227233/579895). Hay que ir a `Eclipse Preferences / Team / Git / Configuration / User Settings` y en la sección `Core` añadir (o modificar si ya existe) esto:

```
key: autocrlf
value: false
```

Comment: correctisimo, con lo de ignorar los espacios en blanco a funcionado perfectamente, muchas gracias.